# Ubuntu unusably slow on Acer Aspire One

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, acer, ubuntu-netbook, aspire-one

It's a dual core Atom 1.33Ghz processor (2G ram). Bought it with Windows 7 illegally installed, but it always ran extremely slow anyway, so I wiped it and installed 14.04.

I expected it to be slow, but it's totally unusable. Like 80 seconds to open the unity search, then 10 seconds per letter when you type. Some things are almost usable, but others are impossibly slow. Also, browsers freeze up after about 5 minutes of use. So do most other programs.

I've disabled graphics, switched to GNOME, tried to install nvidia drivers, but nothing helps. Like, no difference at all.

Would an older version of Ubuntu run faster, or am I missing something fundamental? I ask because [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/200908-3469/) seems to indicate 12.04 is the preferred system, though maybe it's just an old page?

Comment: Xubuntu and Lubuntu are faster options for low resource machines.

Comment: It may be the graphics requirements of Ubuntu that are causing many of your problems - Ubuntu itself uses a lot of GPU time to display pretty effects, and if your processor is busy doing that...  Two things that you could try  1)  check to see if you have a graphics card which is being used  2) Run Lubuntu, which has a much lighter interface.

Comment: Hi brentonstrine, I was going to answer but thi is actually a question similar to the one xangua mentions about Ubuntu on low end hardware. For an Atom processor with 2 GB I highly recommend Lubuntu, followed by Xubuntu as the duplicate question points out in the answer by fossfreedom.